# PATH not extended via source command in cron command on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell, cron

I just installed Mac OS X. I do not want to use launchd. For some reason, when I source my .bash_profile in a cron command, the PATH does not update. However, when the same cron command is run at the shell, the PATH does update. Also manually updating the PATH in the cron command does work.

So this cron line updates the `PATH`:

```
34       03     *              *       *  PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH ; echo $PATH
```

While this cron line:

```
34       03     *              *       *  source $HOME/.bash_profile ; echo $PATH
```

shows this result:

```
From anicca@terrences-mbp.home  Thu Sep 25 03:40:01 2014
X-Original-To: anicca
Delivered-To: anicca@terrences-mbp.home
From: anicca@terrences-mbp.home (Cron Daemon)
To: anicca@terrences-mbp.home
Subject: Cron <anicca@terrences-mbp> source $HOME/.bash_profile ; echo $PATH
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=anicca>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=anicca>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/anicca>
Date: Thu, 25 Sep 2014 03:40:00 -0400 (EDT)

/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

but nonetheless the same command at the shell does update the `PATH`:

```
[~/prg/binary-martingale/src]$ source $HOME/.bash_profile ; echo $PATH
/Users/anicca/anaconda/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anicca/anaconda/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anicca/anaconda/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anicca/anaconda/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anicca/anaconda/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anicca/anaconda/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/Users/anicca/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
[~/prg/binary-martingale/src]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` built-in command won't work the way you want from cron because **cron daemon starts a subshell from your HOME directory** to run your job. `source` command merely prevents forking another subshell within that child process.

#### [An introduction to cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the cron you should start your shell script, e.g.

```
34       03     *              *       *  /path/to/my/script.sh
```

and in the `script.sh` you should setup the needed environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that you can use to source your .bashrc or .bash_profile and then execute a command line:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source ~/.bash_profile

echo "CMDLINE: $@"
echo "PATH: $PATH"

eval $@
```